# how to order confluence pages via the api?

Tags: api, json, confluence, rpc

I'm uploading a few hundreds of pages to Confluence 5.3.1 (no option to upgrade right now) using a Python script talking to Confluence via JSON-RPC ([Remote Confluence Methods](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Remote+Confluence+Methods) and friends).

I need to control the order of child pages via the API.

So far I haven't found a way to do that. I tried to "movePage" within the parent and the "append" order but it doesn't make a difference - the child pages keep being sorted alphabetically.

Is there a way to do that via the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing code which received the required page order and used Confluence 'movePage' method to move each page to the right position. The trick was to move the pages in order from top to bottom.